# Number to UTF-8 char

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8

In Node.js I'm able to print to the console a Japanese character like this:

```
console.log('\u3041');
```

If I have 3041 as a number, for instance because it is randomly generated, how do I print the corresponding UTF-8 sigil?

```
const charNumber = 3041;

// of course this doesn't work, but I need something like that:
console.log(`\u${charNumber}`);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the HEX representation with `.fromCharCode` by replacing `\u` with `0x`:

```js
const charNumber = 3041;
console.log(String.fromCharCode(`0x${charNumber}`));
```